# How do I install a Dart package globally?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

Does Pub Package Manager provide a way to install packages globally?

I have been a node.js developer for a while and I was wondering if there was a `pub` equivalent of `npm install -g <package_name>`

If there is a way to install packages globally, is there a way to register binary scripts which can be installed to be invoked like shell commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**dependencies**

All pub packages are installed globally (a unique subdirectory below `~/.pub-cache/` for Mac/Linux `AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache` in Windows, for each package version) and is then only linked to your project you add the dependency in `pubspec.yaml`.

Actually `~/pub-cache` is only global for a user not global as for the entire system. I don't know npm well but I think `npm install -g` installs it global to the system. There is nothing similar in Dart but you don't install a package in Dart anyway. When you use a Pub package in the same version in different packages it is saved only once on the drive.

**global package executables**

Packages containing executable scripts can be globally (per user) activated using `pub global activate ...`. If you add the `~/.pub-cache/bin/` directory to your path you can run these executable Dart scripts just by their name (like `tuneup` for the `tuneup` package) or with `pub global run packagename:scriptName` (like `pub global run tuneup:tuneup`) If script and package name are the same you can omit the `:scriptName` part.

**local package executables**

You can also run scripts from dependencies of your current project with `pub run packageName:scriptName` (like `pub run test` for running unit tests)

Comment: Installing packages globally with the support of binary scripts allows authoring of tools or utilities (like code-gen, linters, etc) and still using the convenience and consistency of `pub`. This is one of the features of `npm` (or even rubygems) that I quite like. Pub can still use a local version (local to the app) of a package over the global one if a local one exists.

Comment: I also believe, the bug report you were referring to is - [Issue 7874](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=7874)